# Save object to attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

I'm using [Shippinglogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/shippinglogic) to pull data from various carriers.

What I want to do is save the data that is pulled to my table.

So I'm trying to do that like so:

```
ups = Shippinglogic::UPS.new
self.attributes = ups.track(:tracking_number => number)
self.save
```

Here's what the `ups.track` call returns:

```
>> ups.track(:tracking_number => '1ZX2988X0386964132')
=> #<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details:0x1093ba7e0 @origin_country="US", @service_type="GROUND", @destination_state="AL", @origin_state="KY", @signature_name=nil, @destination_city="BIRMINGHAM", @events=[#<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details::Event:0x109383010 @country="US", @name="DELIVERED", @postal_code="35242", @city="BIRMINGHAM", @type="D", @state="AL", @occurred_at=Tue Aug 16 13:44:00 -0500 2011>, #<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details::Event:0x109382d90 @country="US", @name="OUT FOR DELIVERY", @postal_code=nil, @city="BIRMINGHAM", @type="I", @state="AL", @occurred_at=Tue Aug 16 07:46:00 -0500 2011>, #<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details::Event:0x1093b1dc0 @country="US", @name="ARRIVAL SCAN", @postal_code=nil, @city="BIRMINGHAM", @type="I", @state="AL", @occurred_at=Tue Aug 16 07:00:00 -0500 2011>, #<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details::Event:0x109382c50 @country="US", @name="DEPARTURE SCAN", @postal_code=nil, @city="NASHVILLE", @type="I", @state="TN", @occurred_at=Tue Aug 16 03:45:00 -0500 2011>, #<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details::Event:0x109382098 @country="US", @name="ARRIVAL SCAN", @postal_code=nil, @city="NASHVILLE", @type="I", @state="TN", @occurred_at=Tue Aug 16 00:19:00 -0500 2011>, #<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details::Event:0x10937d0c0 @country="US", @name="DEPARTURE SCAN", @postal_code=nil, @city="LEXINGTON", @type="I", @state="KY", @occurred_at=Mon Aug 15 21:36:00 -0500 2011>, #<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details::Event:0x109375e38 @country="US", @name="ORIGIN SCAN", @postal_code=nil, @city="LEXINGTON", @type="I", @state="KY", @occurred_at=Mon Aug 15 16:08:00 -0500 2011>, #<Shippinglogic::UPS::Track::Details::Event:0x109370bb8 @country="US", @name="BILLING INFORMATION RECEIVED", @postal_code=nil, @city=nil, @type="M", @state=nil, @occurred_at=Mon Aug 15 12:18:56 -0500 2011>], @origin_city="CAMPBELLSVILLE", @delivery_at=Tue Aug 16 13:44:00 -0500 2011, @status="DELIVERED", @destination_country="US">
```

But the object that is returned by Shippinglogic doesn't save to `attributes`.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the `track` method returns an object. You can't easily store it. So instead, you need to use its methods to store what you're really interested in.

Eg. store the status and signature name

```
ups = Shippinglogic::UPS.new
track = ups.track(:tracking_number => number) # save  the results of the lookup 
        # since the lookup is expensive
self.status = track.status
self.signature_name = track.signature_name 
save # no need to say "self.save"
```

**Added**

Depending on how the #track objects are defined, it may be reasonable to serialize the entire object into your data record. Then re-create the #track object when you need to print things out. [Article](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/)

Another issue is that eventually, presumably, you're going to want to present the tracking information to as a string to a human. If so, then simply do the conversion to strings/html etc early and store the resulting string in your record.

Comment: Good point on the self.save, almost missed that when I edited his code :)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, primarily because there are about a dozen methods for a single carrier that I want to store (and there are at least a dozen carriers I'll be doing this for). All the methods are already in Shippinglogic, and can be mapped directly to database columns names, so I feel like I'm just duplicating things by setting them again.

Comment: @Shpigford -- you can use the "send" method and metaprogramming to save lines of code. You cpuld also try serializing and de-serializing the entire object. That can be tricky to get working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the Shippinglogic github README. Isn't the usage supposedly:

```
ups = Shippinglogic::UPS.new
tracking = ups.track(:tracking_number => number)
self.attributes = tracking.attributes
save
```

Check the Flexibility section of their README, and you'll the tracking.attributes method.

Update:

If you need to quickly get the origin_*, destination_*, signature_name, service_type, status, delivery_at, and tracking_number you can do something like this:

```
ups = Shippinglogic::UPS.new
tracking = ups.track(:tracking_number => number)
self.attributes = [:origin_city, ...].inject({}) do |attrs, attr_name|
  attrs[attr_name] = tracking.try(attr_name)
  attrs
end
save
```

But this is a quick and dirty way of doing it. I'm not even sure if you save a lot of characters of code (perhaps). But it's not as readable as explicitly assigning it one by one.

Comment: I initially tried that, but in the example above, the only thing returned by `tracking.attributes` is `{:tracking_number=>"1ZX2988X0386964132"}`

Comment: I see. I've also read your other comment, and it seems you want to avoid having to access the attributes one by one. But have you at least checked if they have values? I guess that's the point of your code in the question, right (the object returned by track has a lot of other values)? But which attributes there do you specifically need?

Comment: That's what's already in Shippinglogic and can be easily customized: https://github.com/binarylogic/shippinglogic/blob/master/lib/shippinglogic/ups/track.rb

Comment: Ok, I can see that the track method returns an instance of Details class. So I guess you want origin_*, destination_*, signature_name, service_type, status, and delivery_at, correct? Let me update my answer in a bit.